# Merging Intervals out of hyphenated string ranges

Tags: go, data-structures

I have a string like this:
`ports := []string{"1", "2-7", "12-1200", "10-500"}`

I would like to make an integer set out of this like the output should be :

`[]intSet{ 1, 2-7, 10-1200 }`

Where `intSet` is some kind of integer set from which I am able to easily remove and add elements.

### Update 1

`intSet` is a list of `sets`.
So, `2-7` is also a set.

### Update 2

Here the largest set is merged.

e.g.

- "1" -> 1
- "2-7" -> 2-7
- "12-1200" & "10-500" => "10..12.....500....1200" -> 10-1200

Since it's a `set` so it encompasses a unique range for this, a range which covers the whole set.

Comment: what is the type of `inSet`, Is `2-7` is an int? or string? do you want to merge sets?

Comment: @nipuna I've updated the question. yes `2-7` is a set. `intSet` is a list of sets

Comment: `"12-1200", "10-500"` what happen to this? merged as `10 - 1200`?

Comment: @nipuna
Yes. It's a merged set, so that would have that.

Comment: Why is it merged? How? `"10-500"` is not a subset of `"12-1200"`

Comment: @nipuna have updated the question with explanation for the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235686/discussion-between-nipuna-and-ricizawu).

Comment: This resembles the merging intervals: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merging-intervals/

Comment: Thanks @p9sh . have updated the question for easier understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

type intSet struct {
    start int
    end   int
}

func (s intSet) String() string {
    if s.start == s.end {
        return fmt.Sprintf("%d", s.start)
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d-%d", s.start, s.end)
}

func (s intSet) in(i int) bool {
    return s.start <= i && i <= s.end
}

func (s *intSet) union(set intSet) {
    if set.start < s.start {
        s.start = set.start
    }

    if set.end > s.end {
        s.end = set.end
    }
}

func insert(set intSet, is []intSet) bool {
    for i, s := range is {
        if s.in(set.start) || s.in(set.end) {
            is[i].union(set)
            return true
        }
        //updated here with thankful to @mh-cbon
        if set.in(s.start) || set.in(s.end) {
            is[i].union(set)
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func main() {
    var set []intSet
    ports := []string{"1", "2-7", "12-1200", "10-500", "9-5500"}
    for _, port := range ports {
        s := strings.Split(port, `-`)
        if len(s) < 1 || len(s) > 2 {
            log.Fatalln(`set cannot have multiple values or no value`)
        }
        start, err := strconv.Atoi(s[0])
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
        end := start
        if len(s) == 2 {
            end, err = strconv.Atoi(s[1])
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalln(err)
            }
        }

        temSet := intSet{
            start: start,
            end:   end,
        }
        if !insert(temSet, set) {
            set = append(set, temSet)
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(set) //[1 2-7 9-5500]
}
```

run [here](https://play.golang.org/p/g9RPBhcLMud)

Comment: @mh-cbon I didn't get this

Comment: with `ports := []string{"1", "2-7", "12-1200", "10-500", "9-5500"}` the output is `[1 10-1200 2-7 9-5500]` But it is not correct because `10-1200` is in the range of `9-5500`, so, IF, i am correct, the output should be `[1 2-7 9-5500]`

Comment: the solution lacks a pre sorting to the iteration process. But it cannot b done with only `strings.Sort`. My understanding is that we must first build a list of ranges with numerical values, sort that lst based on the start range, then apply the algorithm you wrote.

Comment: Yeah that also can be used.

Comment: neat improvement i did not understand at first.